# IntelliJ IDEA Remote build Cordova applications for iOS

Tags: ios, macos, cordova, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I am using IntelliJ IDEA on Windows with the cordova plugin to develop an ionic application.
Now I would like to build and deploy the application to an iOS device. I have the iOS device attached to a separate Machine running macOS Sierra and Xcode.
I have looked at the Run configurations settings. And there is a remote run. However there is no documentation and I am not sure how to specify a target.

There is [extensive documentation](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/ios-guide/#install) from Microsoft on how to achieve this with Visual Studio  and [npm remotebuild](https://www.npmjs.com/package/remotebuild), but I have found no similar solution for IntelliJ IDEA.

Is this possible with IntelliJ IDEA? If so: how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the official Jetbrains support:

> The IntelliJ IDEA Cordova/Phonegap/Ionic run configuration simply provides the UI for the Cordova CLI, so running it with the Run command selected is more or less equal to running `ionic run` in the command line. At the moment we don't have any supported workflows for deploying an app to a phone connected to a different machine.

Ekaterina Prigara  04 Apr 2017, 14:40, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-26322

So the workaround will be to create a different workflow with a CI server building for iOS automatically on new commits.